# jQuery function not triggering in a conditional loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

When `scanStatus == 'limit'` the `centerPopup()` and `loadPopup()` functions do not trigger.

The functions are called from a file called `js/count.js`. The file is available [here](http://webwordcount.com/js/count.js).

These are my functions, stored in `js/popup.js`:

```
// Loading popup with jQuery magic!
function loadPopup() {
    // Loads popup only if it is disabled
    if (popupStatus == 0) {
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.7"
        });

        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");

        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}

// Centering popup
function centerPopup() {
    // Request data for centering
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
    var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();

    // Centering
    $("#popupContact").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight / 2 - popupHeight / 2,
        "left": windowWidth / 2 - popupWidth / 2
    });

    // Only need force for IE6
    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });
}
```

Both files are included in the HTML like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var uid = "rZCENk6w";
    var website = "http://www.engadget.com";
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/count.js"></script>
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Where's the code that's supposed to be calling them?

Comment: please provide part of html to test the situation where you are checking the condition to invoke the popup..?

Comment: umm the function that checks whether its at its limit is commented out.... did you do that because it isnt working?

Comment: Laurence: Yea, it was because it wasn't working. It turned out to be a  simple syntax error and I was thinking it was something more complex due to my lack of jQuery knowledge. Thanks for all the replies and help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the code [found in the linked file (near the bottom)](http://webwordcount.com/js/popup.js), the methods are never called on the document becoming ready because they are commented out:

```
//if (scanStatus == 'limit') {
    //LOADING POPUP
    //Click the button event!
    //$("#button").click(function(){
        //centering with css
        //centerPopup();
        //load popup
        //loadPopup();
//});}
```

You would need to uncomment them in order to execute them accordingly:

```
if (scanStatus == 'limit') {
    $("#button").click(function() {
        centerPopup();
        loadPopup();
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 - something about your answer to this question, combined with your user name really made me smile

Comment: That was while trying to debug, #button does not exist. Based on your answer I tried something else and it worked. My problem was a syntax error.